# camel-ssh key based authentication

Tags: ssh, apache-camel, blueprint-osgi

I am trying to execute ssh commands through camel route. I am getting below 
 error can anyone help me to resolve the issue. I was able to execute commands by using username and password.

public key I copied in authorized_keys in server.
I am using blueprint dsl.

```
 < to uri="ssh://admin@10.23.24.41:22? certResource=classpath:test_rsa&amp;timeout=5000"/>
```

test_rsa is the filename where public key is present.

```
Server at /10.23.24.41:22 presented unverified DSA key: 
8a:40:91:2a:16:90:8c:c4:06:b1:1f:79:74:2f:08:09

EXCEPTION MESSAGEstrong text=Cannot execute command: 
ls /opt/esb/jboss-fuse-6.2.1.redhat-084. Exchange[Message: 
ls /opt/esb/jboss-fuse-6.2.1.redhat-084]. Caused by: [java.io.IOException - Error performing public key authentication] 
STACKTRACE=org.apache.camel.CamelExchangeException: Cannot execute command: 
ls /opt/esb/jboss-fuse-6.2.1.redhat-084. Exchange[Message: 
ls /opt/esb/jboss-fuse-6.2.1.redhat-084]. Caused by: [java.io.IOException - Error performing public key authentication] 
at org.apache.camel.component.ssh.SshProducer.process(SshProducer.java:64) 
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelperProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)atorg.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:139)atorg.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)atorg.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)atorg.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)atorg.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)atorg.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)atorg.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)atorg.apache.camel.component.directvm.DirectVmProcessor.process(DirectVmProcessor.java:55)atorg.apache.camel.component.directvm.DirectVmProducer.process(DirectVmProducer.java:55)atorg.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:139)atorg.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)atorg.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)atorg.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)atorg.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)atorg.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)atorg.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)atorg.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfConsumer1.asyncInvoke(CxfConsumer.java:95) 
at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfConsumer1.invoke(CxfConsumer.java:75)atorg.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59) 
at java.util.concurrent.ExecutorsRunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)atjava.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)atorg.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor2.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:126) 
at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37) 
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:131) 
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307) 
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) 
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:251) 
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.doService(JettyHTTPDestination.java:261) 
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPHandler.handle(JettyHTTPHandler.java:70) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1088) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1024) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:984) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnectionRequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1045)atorg.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:861)atorg.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:236)atorg.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)atorg.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)atorg.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error performing public key authentication 
at org.apache.sshd.client.auth.deprecated.UserAuthPublicKey.next(UserAuthPublicKey.java:90) 
at org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientUserAuthServiceOld.processUserAuth(ClientUserAuthServiceOld.java:150) 
at org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientUserAuthServiceOld.auth(ClientUserAuthServiceOld.java:183) 
at org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientUserAuthService.auth(ClientUserAuthService.java:109) 
at org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientSessionImpl.tryAuth(ClientSessionImpl.java:182) 
at org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientSessionImpl.authPublicKey(ClientSessionImpl.java:173) 
at org.apache.camel.component.ssh.SshHelper.sendExecCommand(SshHelper.java:82) 
at org.apache.camel.component.ssh.SshProducer.process(SshProducer.java:59) 
… 47 more 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
at org.apache.sshd.common.util.KeyUtils.getKeyType(KeyUtils.java:67) 
at org.apache.sshd.client.auth.deprecated.UserAuthPublicKey.next(UserAuthPublicKey.java:61) 
… 54 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of certResource=classpath:test_rsa,
try: privateKeyFile=/path/to/test_rsa

< to uri="ssh://admin@10.23.24.41:22?privateKeyFile=/path/to/test_rsa & amp; knownHostsFile=/path/to/known_hosts"/>

your known_hosts file can be empty initially.
this worked for me. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its working fine. Only mistake I did is instead of private key, I copied public key.

Comment: yes, only private key is sufficient I think, you need to only use these 2 options: known_hosts and privateKeyFile.

Comment: yes private key itself is sufficient.known_hosts or public key is not needed. I used certResource directly instead of privateKeyFile its working for me.

Comment: Please mark my answer is helpful. It will help me to gain some score. :)

Comment: I tried marking when u have given reply to me but I don't have reputation that's why it's not updating

Comment: You can accept the answer. It will give you reputation score too. Don't go for up arrow key. But the accepting answer.

Comment: privateKeyFile is not a parameter

 Failed to resolve endpoint: ssh://id342@ip-10-112-54-51.eu-central-1.compute.internal:22?privateKeyFile=%2Fhome%2Fid342%2F.ssh%2Fid_rsa_scs_068.pem&timeout=10000 due to: There are 1 parameters that couldn't be set on the endpoint. Check the uri if the parameters are spelt correctly and that they are properties of the endpoint. Unknown parameters=[{privateKeyFile=/home/id342/.ssh/id_rsa_scs_068.pem}]

Answer (score 2):

I forgot to add test_rsa as private key and test_rsa.pub in class path. After adding I was able to communicate with the server.

[image]